# What can be the reason that I get TypeInitializationException when I call a static method on a class?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I have a static method on a public class. Example:

```
public class MyClass {
 public static bool Test() { return true; }
}
```

And I call this from a unit test in another class:

```
MyClass.Test();
```

When the debugger comes to this it throws: TypeInitializationException:

> {"The type initializer for 'Xxxxx.Yyyyy.MyClass' threw an exception."}

Inner Exception says:

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: container"}

Any idea why it may be the case?

Note: This is a class in a console application - if it is important.

Comment: Look at any static constructors and any static variable initializers - and please post the full TypeInitializationException including the inner exception.

Comment: That's not the full exception - it's just the messages. Could you post the *full* exception, stack trace and all? That should make it pretty clear.

Comment: O.K. This seems to be something to do with IoC containers.

Comment: Quite possibly. If you post the stack trace, it'll become more obvious...

Comment: No need Jon; I have checked the trace and it confirms the assumption. But thanks for leading it to that way :)

Comment: It *is* important that you learn from this though: the more information you provide in a question, the less you'll be asking answerers to basically guess... see http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `TypeInitializationException` is thrown when an exception occurs during the initialization of the *type* (as opposed to an instance of the type).

This generally means it is caused by an exception in a static constructor or where static fields are initialized.

One important thing to bear in mind when trying to find the cause is this: Once a type has thrown this exception once - it will *always* throw it every other time you try and access the type. This means that to get to the bottom of it, you may have to hunt down where it is first thrown, rather than where it is thrown subsequently.

*[Edit: in response to your updated question]*
Can you post a more complete `MyClass`? It is doing something when the type itself is initialized causing it to throw this.

Comment: O.K. This seems to be something to do with IoC containers. I have followed your advse and Set the "Break When an aexception is: Common Language Runtime Exception" and found that there is some setting problem for the IoC. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help you: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017043/typeinitializationexception-exception-on-creating-an-object)

Usually the `TypeInitializationException` hides the real exception which can be viewed via `InnerException`. If this doesn't help, you shoud think about creating a [singleton](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx) where you have better control to catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to find my problem with this one as well. I realized I was using a Dictionary in my static method which contained two identical definitions thus resulting in an error. However, this inner exception was covered up by the TypeInitializationException. I would try looking at the actual method to see if there are any errors within your code. Thanks,

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> _dictionaryTest = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"zzz", "zzzz"},
    {"zzz", "zzzz"},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I hit this one for a while when putting together some test data in static class members.  Switching from `readonly` fields to read-only properties set the order correctly.

Answer (score -1):

In the past ive gotten these from dodgy builds, try cleaning your solution and rebuilding. Also check the configuration manager to make sure your build config is correct

Comment: Any "specific" thing that I should check on the build config?

Comment: Things that look different to your current build, ie if you are using Debug x86 (ie for a console app) if any of your projects arent using debug