# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, .net

I've a simple class MyClass with a method defined in a DLL, now I refer to this DLL in another code and try to initialise object like this `Myclass obj = new MyClass()`. I'm not sure why compiler is throwing `NullReferenceException`. Please assist

DLL:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(){}
    public void method()
    {
         //some code
    }
}
```

Other code:

```
void main()
{
    MyClass obj=new MyClass(); //This is where I get NullReferenceException error
}
```

Comment: What's inside `MyClass` constructor? and do you get `TypeInitializationException` or `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Check the inner exception. This type exception (`TypeInitializationException`) is usually a sign that some static field initialization or the static constructor have thrown an error.

Comment: Might be related to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017043/typeinitializationexception-exception-on-creating-an-object) question

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, inner exception is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @Aniruddha and the call stack for he inner exception ? Where does that lead to ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, you are right, it leads to a static string variable, but I'm still unable to comprehend why it's throwing error: static string SqlConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RMDB.Database"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Does the RMDB.Database exist in your app.config  file ? Not in the dll but in you exe project ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, No.

Comment: @Aniruddha It should. The app.config is the one that will be used for you application. It must contain the connection string that your dll class is using.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir, Genius. sheer genius. Thanks!!. It worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For posterity, since we found the answer in the comments:

`TypeInitializationException` is usually caused by an error in static field initialization or static constructor execution.

Indeed we found that the inner exception stack trace pointed to :

```
SqlConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RMDB.Database"].Conn‌​ectionString
```

This error is caused by the fact that the connection string `RMDB.Database` was not specified in the `app.config` for the application. Connection strings (event those used from dlls) must be specified in the `app.config` of the application using the connection.